MCMC and binary logistic regressions with zero events
I've data with binary outcome and binary dependent variables.
The problem is the zero events presence for almost one variable.
I have to do binary logistic regression with OR (95% CI) estimate and I can't due to zero events.
I've tried exact-like inference in logistic regression models (elrm R package) with no result.
how can I solve it?
here's the code for the elrm:
> x <- xtabs(~dead + interaction(volo_1, NACA_cat), data = db)
> x
     interaction(volo_1, NACA_cat)
morto  0.0  1.0  0.1  1.1
    0 2340  273  303   81
    1    0    0   86   21 

> cdat <- cdat <- data.frame(volo_1 = rep(0:1, 2), NACA_cat = rep(0:1, each = 2), admit = x[2, ], ntrials = colSums(x))
> cdat 
    volo_1 NACA_cat admit ntrials
0.0      0        0     0    2340
1.0      1        0     0     273
0.1      0        1    86     389
1.1      1        1    21     102
> m.volo_1 <- elrm(formula = admit/ntrials ~ volo_1, interest = ~volo_1, iter = 22000, dataset = cdat, burnIn = 2Progress: 100%                      

Generation of the Markov Chain required 3 secs
Conducting inference ...
Inference required 0 secs
> ## summary of model including estimates and CIs
> summary(m.volo_1)

Call:

elrm(formula = admit/ntrials ~ volo_1, interest = ~volo_1, iter = 22000, dataset = cdat, burnIn = 2000)


Results:

       estimate p-value p-value_se mc_size
volo_1  0.63666 0.02295    0.00166   20000


95% Confidence Intervals for Parameters

            lower    upper
volo_1 0.06414017 1.352148
> 
> 
> 
> m.NACA_cat <- elrm(formula = admit/ntrials ~ NACA_cat, interest = ~NACA_cat, iter = 22000, dataset = cdat, burnIn = 2Progress: 100%                      

Generation of the Markov Chain required 4 secs
Conducting inference ...
Inference required 0 secs
Warning message:
'NACA_cat' observed value of the sufficient statistic was not sampled 
> ## summary of model including estimates and CIs
> summary(m.NACA_cat)

Call:

elrm(formula = admit/ntrials ~ NACA_cat, interest = ~NACA_cat, iter = 22000, dataset = cdat, burnIn = 2000)


Results:

         estimate p-value p-value_se mc_size
NACA_cat       NA       0          0   20000


95% Confidence Intervals for Parameters

         lower upper
NACA_cat    NA    NA


here's the code for the binary logistic regression:
> full.model <- glm(morto ~ volo_1  + NACA_cat , data = db,family=binomial())
> logistic.display(full.model)

Logistic regression predicting morto : 1 vs 0 
 
                 crude OR(95%CI)       adj. OR(95%CI)        P(Wald's test) P(LR-test)
volo_1: 1 vs 0   1.82 (1.12,2.98)      0.91 (0.53,1.56)      0.741          0.739     
                                                                                      
NACA_cat: 1 vs 0 647257526.44 (0,Inf)  653272824.33 (0,Inf)  0.972          < 0.001   
                                                                                      
Log-likelihood = -257.3593
No. of observations = 3104
AIC value = 520.7187

EDIT:
Here is a MRE with fewer records but the same problem:
db<- data.frame( morto =  c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                 volo_1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                 NACA_dic = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))



db$volo_1<- as.factor(db$volo_1)


db$morto<- as.factor(db$morto)


db$NACA_dic<- as.factor(db$NACA_dic)



full.model <- glm(morto ~ volo_1 + NACA_dic  , data = db,family=binomial())

logistic.display(full.model)

x <- xtabs(~morto + interaction(volo_1, NACA_dic), data = db)


cdat <- cdat <- data.frame(volo_1 = rep(0:1, 2), NACA_dic = rep(0:1, each = 2), 
                           admit = x[2, ], ntrials = colSums(x))
cdat 


m.volo_1 <- elrm(formula = admit/ntrials ~ volo_1, interest = ~volo_1, iter = 22000, 
                 dataset = cdat, burnIn = 2000)
summary(m.volo_1)

m.NACA_dic <- elrm(formula = admit/ntrials ~ NACA_dic, interest = ~NACA_dic, iter = 22000, 
                   dataset = cdat, burnIn = 2000)
summary(m.NACA_cat)


Here is the problem:
> m.NACA_dic <- elrm(formula = admit/ntrials ~ NACA_dic, interest = ~NACA_dic, iter = 22000, 
+                    dataset = cdat, burnIn = 2Progress: 100%                      

Generation of the Markov Chain required 3 secs
Conducting inference ...
Inference required 0 secs
Warning message:
'NACA_dic' observed value of the sufficient statistic was not sampled 
> summary(m.NACA_cat)

Call:

elrm(formula = admit/ntrials ~ NACA_cat, interest = ~NACA_cat, iter = 22000, dataset = cdat, burnIn = 2000)


Results:

         estimate p-value p-value_se mc_size
NACA_cat       NA       0          0   20000


95% Confidence Intervals for Parameters

         lower upper
NACA_cat    NA    NA


Have you considered a penalized method (e.g. see the brglm2 package), or a Bayesian method with regularizing priors (e.g. see the rstanarm package)?

(and could we have a [mcve] please?)

@BenBolker Thank you for your suggestions, I don't know these methods. I'll try them. I've added a MRE. I hope this is ok. Thank you so much for your help!

SOLVED:
following the suggestions of @BenBolker I implemented Bias Reduction in Binomial-Response Generalized Linear Models with the brglm package
> model<-brglm(morto ~ volo_1 + NACA_dic , data = db,family=binomial, model = TRUE, method = "brglm.fit",
+              pl = FALSE, x = FALSE, y = TRUE, contrasts = NULL)
> 
> summary(model)

Call:
brglm(formula = morto ~ volo_1 + NACA_dic, family = binomial, 
    data = db, model = TRUE, method = "brglm.fit", pl = FALSE, 
    x = FALSE, y = TRUE, contrasts = NULL)


Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)  -4.5591     1.4144  -3.223  0.00127 **
volo_11      -1.3200     0.7845  -1.683  0.09244 . 
NACA_dic1     4.6583     1.4325   3.252  0.00115 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 138.942  on 133  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  92.711  on 131  degrees of freedom
Penalized deviance: 90.11255 
AIC:  98.711 

> exp(coef(model))
 (Intercept)      volo_11    NACA_dic1 
  0.01047146   0.26712352 105.45428986 
> exp(confint(model))
Profiling the ordinary deviance for the corresponding ML fit...
Profiling the penalized deviance for the supplied fit...
Calculating confidence intervals for the ML fit using deviance profiles...
Calculating confidence intervals for the BR fit using penalized likelihood profiles...
                  2.5 %     97.5 %
(Intercept)  0.00000000 0.07274017
volo_11      0.03224977 1.06917625
NACA_dic1   14.10469036        Inf
> coef(summary(model))[,'Pr(>|z|)']
(Intercept)     volo_11   NACA_dic1 
0.001266712 0.092437418 0.001146851 


